# Recursion depth of 256 exceeded in simple loop

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to do a really basic loop that creates a sequence of functions using an iterative process. I used an earlier version of *Mathematica* many years ago and thought this worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the basic idea applied to the function g(x)=x. I keep getting error of Recursion depth of 256 exceeded. It also doesn't show a plot.

```
g[x_] := x;
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++, 
 f1[x_] := .25*g[2*x] + .25*2*x;
 f2[x_] := .25*g[2*x - 1] - .25*(2*x - 1) + .25;
 g[x_] := If[0 <= x <= .5, f1[x], f2[x]]
];
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to Plot some point x,g[x].
Ok, need to figure out what g[x] is.
Ok, that happens to be f1[x].
Ok, need to figure out what f1[x] is.
That is defined to be g[x].
Ok, need to figure out what g[x] is.
Ok, that happens to be f2[x].
Ok, need to figure out what f2[x] is.
That is defined to be g[x].
And this happens over and over until Mathematica's check for runaway recursion stops it.

So describe very very clearly to yourself what your sequence of functions is supposed to be.
From that think carefully about how to turn that into Mathematica code without infinite recursion.